Add Custom Tax Value to WooCommerce order programmatically
I am creating a WooCommerce order programmatically, but I cannot seem to get Tax added to A custom shipping method. Here is my code:
$shipping = new WC_Order_Item_Shipping();
$shipping->set_props(
    array(
        'method_title' => "Tracked (2-3 business days)",
        'method_id'    => "advanced_flat_rate_shipping:779",
        'taxes'        => array(),
        'tax'          => array(),
        'calc_tax'     => 'per_item',
        'total'        => 4,
        'tax_class'    => 'standard',
        'total_tax'    => 0.80,
    )
);

here is a snapshot of an order with the tax field blank - https://snipboard.io/BoWZJT.jpg
